# MySQL counter column not populating correctly using Python and pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a MySQL query that uses variables to produce a counter:

```
select
  zz.work_order,
  zz.op_number,
  @num := if(@wo = zz.work_order, @num+1,1) as 'steps_away',
  @wo := zz.work_order as 'dummyWO'
from
  (
   select
     w.work_order,
     w.op_number
   from
     [sql cut]
   order by
     w.work_order asc,
     r.op_number asc
) as zz
```

When I execute this in MySQL workbench, steps_away is populated correctly.
The first occurrence of a work_order has steps_away = 1, the next occurrence has steps_away = 2, etc. until a new work order is seen and the counter resets.

In Python, I use pandas read_sql and to_sql functions to save the query in a DataFrame and then send it to a database.

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql_cmd, engine)
```

Whether I send this df to a csv with df.to_csv or to a table with df.to_sql, the steps_away column has the value 1 all the way down.

What could be causing the query to look correct when run directly in MySQL vs when it is called in Python?

**UPDATE**

I was testing this some more and found something strange.  When I tried the query in MySQL Workbench again, the values in steps_away were all (incorrectly) equal to 1.  I reran the query immediately with no changes and the values were then populated correctly.

I added the pd.read_sql line twice in Python to match what I did manually and the DataFrame now has the correct values in it for steps_away.  What about using this counter in the query is causing this behavior where sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and where it seems like calling the query twice ensures that the counter column will be populated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was all MySQL-related and had nothing to do with python.
Needed to initialize the variables by setting them to a value first.  Did this in another subquery in the from section and the problem was resolved.

```
select
  zz.work_order,
  zz.op_number,
  @num := if(@wo = zz.work_order, @num+1,1) as 'steps_away',
  @wo := zz.work_order as 'dummyWO'
from
  (
   select
     w.work_order,
     w.op_number
   from
     [sql cut]
   order by
     w.work_order asc,
     r.op_number asc
  ) as zz,
  (
   select
     @num:=0,
     @wo:=''
  ) as r
```